# C++ problems with conversion

Tags: c++, type-conversion, constants

I have one semestral work (own double linked list) and our teacher want this definition of class DoubleList:

```
template <typename T>   //just part of all methods
class DoubleList { 
public: 

    DoubleList(void);   //We HAVE TO follow this definitions 

    void AddFirst(const T &);     //const!
    T &AccessActual(void); 
    T RemoveFirst(void);
}
```

My question is, how can I define a node? `AddFirst` have const argument and other methods haven't. Data must be set in constructor and then they can't be changed. Is this task so limited or are here other ways to complete the task?

Here is my actual `Node`:

```
template <class U>
        class Node{
            Node<U> * next;
            Node<U> * previous;
            const U * data;
        public:
            Node(const U *data){   //
                next = NULL;
                previous = NULL;
                this->data = data;
            }
            void SetNext(Node<U> *next) { 
                this->next = next; 
            }
            Node<U> *GetNext(){ return next; }
            void SetPrevious(Node<U> *previous) { 
                this->previous = previous; 
            }
            Node<U> *GetPrevious(){ return previous; }
            const U *GetData() { return data; }
        };
```

Comment: You do not need `(void)` in your method declarations.

Comment: Ed Heal: Does it matter? :D

Comment: Yes - It demonstrates the lack on understanding for the language.

Comment: Ed Heal: (void) is just from task, that create my teacher. I know that there may not be..

Comment: Surely the parents of your teacher created the teacher?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In containers, it's usually better to have a copy of the data so change `const U * data;` to `U data;`

The Node constructor would be easier to use if it had this signature `Node(const U& data)`. No pointers.

The GetData would also have to change. Return a reference. `U& GetData()`.

It is dangerous to hold addresses of data items. If the user of the lists wants that functionality he can use a list that stored pointers (e.g. U=int*)

Answer (score 0):

Your node class seems fine, although i would keep using template argument T instead of U, right now it is confusing.

Your AddFirst() method should simply create a new node and assign the correct next pointer to the new node and the correct prev pointer to the "old" first node and adjust the actual object? what does that refer to?

Your interface of nodes differs from  this one returning a reference instead of a pointer. I find it quite strange that the AccessActual can always return an object, while when the list is empty this can be a nullptr??

example implementation:

```
void AddFirst(const T &)
{
  Node<T>* newNode = new Node<T>(T);
  Node<T>* current = &AccessActual(); // how can there be an actual when the list can be empty or is that impossible?

  {
     while( current.GetPrev() != nullptr )
     {
        current = *current.GetPrev();
     }
     current.SetPrev(newnode);
     newnode->SetNext(current);

  }

}
```